# Adding methods to Eloquent Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a bit confused how I am to add methods to Eloquent models. Here is the code in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $limit = Input::get('limit', false);

        try {
            if ($this->isExpand('posts')) {
                $user = User::with(['posts' => function($query) {
                    $query->active()->ordered();
                }])->findByIdOrUsernameOrFail($id);
            } else {
                $user = User::findByIdOrUsernameOrFail($id);
            }

            $userTransformed = $this->userTransformer->transform($user);

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return $this->respondNotFound('User does not exist');
        }

        return $this->respond([
            'item' => $userTransformed
        ]);
    }
```

And the code in the `User` model:

```
public static function findByIdOrUsernameOrFail($id, $columns = array('*')) {
        if (is_int($id)) return static::findOrFail($id, $columns);

        if ( ! is_null($user = static::whereUsername($id)->first($columns))) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw new ModelNotFoundException;
    }
```

So essentially I'm trying to allow the user to be retrieved by either `user_id` or `username`. I want to preserve the power of `findOrFail()` by creating my own method which checks the `$id` for an `int` or `string`.

When I am retrieving the `User` alone, it works with no problem. When I expand the `posts` then I get the error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::findByIdOrUsernameOrFail()

I'm not sure how I would go about approaching this problem.

Comment: have you tried call the method like this `$user -> findByIdOrUsernameOrFail($id)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call your method in a static and a non-static context, which won't work. To accomplish what you want without duplicating code, you can make use of [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
public function scopeFindByIdOrUsernameOrFail($query, $id, $columns = array('*')) {
    if (is_int($id)) return $query->findOrFail($id, $columns);

    if ( ! is_null($user = $query->whereUsername($id)->first($columns))) {
        return $user;
    }

    throw new ModelNotFoundException;
}
```

You can use it exactly in the way you are trying to now.

---

Also, you can use `firstOrFail`:

```
public function scopeFindByIdOrUsernameOrFail($query, $id, $columns = array('*')) {
    if (is_int($id)) return $query->findOrFail($id, $columns);

    return $query->whereUsername($id)->firstOrFail($columns);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that last solution is exactly what I needed, using a scope in this instance makes more sense, and uses less code (a laravel favorite)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine, but you're trying to use it in two conflicting ways. The one that works as you intended is the one in the `else` clause, like you realised.

The reason the first mention doesn't work is because of two things:

1. You wrote the method as a static method, meaning that you don't call it on an instantiated object. In other words: `User::someStaticMethod()` works, but `$user->someStaticMethod()` doesn't.
2. The code `User::with(...)` returns an Eloquent query `Builder` object. This object can't call your static method.

Unfortunately, you'll either have to duplicate the functionality or circumvent it someway. Personally, I'd probably create a user repository with a non-static method to chain from. Another option is to create a static method on the `User` model that starts the chaining and calls the static method from there.

Edit: Lukas's suggestion of using a scope is of course by far the best option. I did not consider that it would work in this situation.